# Wp-admin page redirecting to 404 error page

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I have an issue when I logged in to Wp-admin dashboard page I can see the wordpress-admin bar on the top of the page but the dashboard page actually redirected to 404 error page. 
I have disabled all the plugins and activated theme to find the problem, and change the code inside .htaccess file to default wordpress code, but nothing worked. 
Also, I have tested to create the test.php page inside the wp-admin directory but it also returned to 404 page when I access to https://example.com/wp-admin/test.php. 
So I think the PHP is not working inside the wp-admin? Has anyone experienced this before and have any more ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check if admin dashboard is accessible with https://example.com/wp-login.php.
If so, do you have any security plugins installed then just deactivate it and check.

Answer (score 0):

Please  take a complete backup of your database and file before
Sometimes, just updating the site URL solves this problem.

Login to your FTP client area
Locate the WP-Config file
Take a backup of WP-Config.php file
Then edit it and add this line of code

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yourdomain.com');
```

Replace the "yourdomain.com" with your original domain(website name).

Comment: I have done that but it did not work either... It is actually logged in with the top admin bar on the page but when I clicked on dashboard or whatever buttons on that bar, it redirected to 404 page. This is pretty weird...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helps. I have detected that the wp-admin folder in the directory has the PHP.ini configuration file, I just removed it then the admin dashboard showed up. So in my case, the problem did not come from security plugins or wrong URL. The Wp-admin folder was controlled by php.ini.